# Finding $\frac{1}{q} $ while $q = 2-\sqrt{3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

As you are familiar with my question as I was stuck in this for several days. Then my teacher suggested this solution for this.

Finding $\frac{1}{q}$:

\begin{align}\frac{1}{q} &= \left(\frac {1}{2-\sqrt{3}}\right) \left(\frac {{2+\sqrt{3}}}{2+\sqrt{3}}\right) \\
\frac{1}{q} &= \frac {2+\sqrt3}{(2)^2-(\sqrt{3})^2} \\
\frac{1}{q} &= \frac {2+\sqrt3}{4-3}\\
\frac{1}{q} &= {2+\sqrt3} \end{align}
As I am answered my question but my confusion stays at it's previous place. Why we multiply the $\frac{1}{q}$ value with it's value, having signs change. Any explanations Please

Comment: $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$, so if $b$ involves a square root, multiplying $a+b$ by $a-b$ will clear it. Note that it does not always work as nicely as your example. For example, try $2+\sqrt7$.

Comment: @almagest, thanks for comment but can you explain it more. Please I am math noob. And explain please why it will not work nicely when we try $2+ \sqrt{7}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a step which has been missed out of the simplification of the bottom of the fraction - remember how to multiply two brackets together (I was taught 'first, inside, outside, last' to remember to multiply all elements in one bracket by all elements in the other - you may have been taught another technique)

\begin{align}(2-\sqrt3)(2+\sqrt3)&=2^2-2\sqrt3+2\sqrt3-(\sqrt3)^2\\
&=2^2-(\sqrt3)^2\\
&=4-3\\
&=1\end{align}

We can see that the inside and outside multiplications cancel each other out - one produces $-2\sqrt3$ and the other produces $+2\sqrt3$

This leads us to the identity that your teacher has used to simplify the bottom of the fraction in one step instead of two

$$(a-b)(a+b)=a^2-b^2$$

This is a common technique to get rid of the 'surds' (square roots) in the bottom of a fraction - you multiply top and bottom of the fraction by the bottom of the fraction with the sign of the surd switched, that is to say that if you have $a+\sqrt b$ on the bottom, then you multiply top and bottom by $a-\sqrt b$

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking a question about conjugates.

$a + \sqrt b, a-\sqrt b$ are are call conjugates.  When we multiply these two irrational numbers together we get a rational number.

i.e. $(a + \sqrt b)(a-\sqrt b) = a^2 - b$

When you have an irrational number of one of these types in the denominator of a fraction, multiplying top and bottom by the conjugate will rationalize the denominator.

Another place that it is common to see conjugates is in the roots of polynomials with rational coefficients.  If $a + \sqrt b$ is a root, its conjugate will also be a root.

Comment: so why we have to rationalize the denominator in my case.

Comment: $q$ is an irrational number in the denominator of a fraction.  It is not required, but it is good style to rationalize the denominator whenever possible.